# Watch remote directory for added files and stream it for reading data over SFTP

Tags: spring-integration, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

I want to add a watch on the remote machine for newly added CSV files or unread. Once files are identified read it according to their timestamp which will be there in the file name. The file will be read using streaming rather coping to the local machine. While the file is getting read, append _reading to the filename and append _read once the file is read. The file will be read over SFTP protocol and I am planning to use spring integration sftp. In case of error while reading file or data in the file is not as per expectation I want to move that file in sub-directory.

I have tried to poll the remote directory and reading once CSV file. Once read I am removing the file from the directory.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-sftp</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

Spring boot version 2.0.3.RELEASE
```

```
 @Bean
    public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost(hostname);
        factory.setPort(22);
        factory.setUser(username);
        factory.setPassword(password);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource<InputStream> sftpMessageSource() {
        SftpStreamingMessageSource messageSource = new SftpStreamingMessageSource(template());
        messageSource.setRemoteDirectory(path);
        messageSource.setFilter(compositeFilters());
        return messageSource;
    }

    public CompositeFileListFilter compositeFilters() {
        return new CompositeFileListFilter()
                .addFilter(new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter(".*csv"));
    }

    @Bean
    public SftpRemoteFileTemplate template() {
        return new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(sftpSessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sftpOutboundListFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(this.sftpMessageSource(), e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(template(), NLST, path).options(Option.RECURSIVE)))
                .filter(compositeFilters())
                .transform(sorter())
                .split()
                .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(template(), GET, "headers['file_remoteDirectory'] + headers['file_remoteFile']").options(STREAM))
                .transform(csvToPojoTransformer())
                .handle(service())
                .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(template(), MV, "headers['file_remoteDirectory'] + headers['file_remoteFile'] + _read"))
                .handle(after())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler sorter() {
        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                List<String> fileNames = (List<String>) message.getPayload();
                Collections.sort(fileNames);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler csvToPojoTransformer() {
        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                InputStream streamData = (InputStream) message.getPayload();
                convertStreamtoObject(streamData, Class.class);
            }
        };
    }

    public List<?> convertStreamtoObject(InputStream inputStream, Class clazz) {
        HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy ms = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy();
        ms.setType(clazz);
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

        CsvToBean cb = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                .withType(clazz)
                .withMappingStrategy(ms)
                .withSkipLines(0)
                .withSeparator('|')
                .withThrowExceptions(true)
                .build();
        return cb.parse();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler service() {
        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                List<Class> csvDataAsListOfPojo = List < Class > message.getPayload();
                // use this
            }
        };
    }
    @Bean
    public ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice after() {
        ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
        advice.setSuccessChannelName("success.input");
        advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("payload + ' was successful'");
        advice.setFailureChannelName("failure.input");
        advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("payload + ' was bad, with reason: ' + #exception.cause.message");
        advice.setTrapException(true);
        return advice;
    }
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow success() {
        return f -> f.handle(System.out::println);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow failure() {
        return f -> f.handle(System.out::println);
    }
```

**Updated Code**

Answer (score 0):

For complex scenarios (list, move, fetch, remove, etc), you should use [SFTP remote file gateways instead](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#sftp-outbound-gateway).

> The SFTP outbound gateway provides a limited set of commands that let you interact with a remote SFTP server:
>
> ls (list files)
>
> nlst (list file names)
>
> get (retrieve a file)
>
> mget (retrieve multiple files)
>
> rm (remove file(s))
>
> mv (move and rename file)
>
> put (send a file)
>
> mput (send multiple files)

Or use the `SftpRemoteFileTemplate` directly from your code.

**EDIT**

In response to your comments; you need something like this

- Inbound Channel Adapter (with poller) - returns directory name
- LS Gateway
- Filter (remove any files already fetched)
- Transformer (sort the list)
- Splitter
- GET Gateway(stream option)
- Transformer (csv to POJO)
- Service (process POJO)

If you add

- RM Gateway

after your service (to remove the remote file), you don't need the filter step.

You might find the Java DSL simpler to assemble this flow...

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(() -> "some/dir", e -> e.poller(...))
        .handle(...) // LS Gateway
        .filter(...)
        .transform(sorter())
        .split
        .handle(...) // GET Gateway
        .transform(csvToPojoTransformer())
        .handle(myService())
        .get()
}
```

Comment: How can I watch for new files that have been added in the remote machine and read them according to the timestamp in the file name? I have used NIO but that is nor helpful in remote machine scenario.

Comment: The gateway list command returns file information (timestamps etc). You can't "watch" but you can poll every so often to detect new files.

Comment: Ok, I will poll the changes but there will be multiple files with name sample_ddmmyy_hhmm.csv and I want to start reading the files one by one with oldest first. I have set messageSource.setMaxFetchSize(1); for reading one file at a time but how can I read the oldest file first. I am new in SFTP integration, sorry if I have asked a trivial question.

Comment: As I said, use the gateway instead; you can list all the remote files, sort them, and fetch them one-at-at-time.

Comment: Ok I will try this, it looks like I have to use gateway operation one by one to achieve my goal. Like ListGateway is there to list all file in directory, is there any other Gateway interface which can be useful? Along with this I am thinking of having a transformer for converting the CSV to bean using openCSV, I am doing it after getting stream object,  can I do inside transformer annotation?

Comment: I have updated the question with new code with your suggestions and what I want to achieve. I have even added advice after all transactions are done to log success and failure. I don`t have SFTP server to test these changes and I am new with SFTP and Spring integration, can you please have a look and suggest.

Comment: I don't think I can help you further on this question; the admins here don't like extended commentary. Any linux/MacOS box has sftp built in; you can easily find an sftp server for windows. I suggest you test your solution and ask a new question if you have problems.